Is rog auracore safe?
I just switched to linux and I cant control my keyboard lights and light zones on my ROG strix g16 2023.There seems to be rogauracore which can control lights,is it safe?

"Is it safe?" is a rhetorical and philosophical question, that can't really be answered. Nothing is 100% secure.
However, I would judge an applications safety rating based on a variety of factors.
For rogauracore this would include:

Author: Seems legit, but not much activity lately.
Last updated: 2 years ago, not good.
Stars: 675, seems ok.
Issues: 54 open, 26 closed (32% closure rating), not so good.

For the other option OpenRGB I would judge:

Author: Seems legit, lots of activity lately.
Last updated: 1 week ago, awesome.
Stars: 2921, awesome.
Issues: 1665 open, 2574 closed (60% closure rating), good.

So I would say OpenRGB is a better choice if your hardware is supported.
